How to put all function/command call output results to different corresponding vars: for stderr, for stdout, for string result and for return code?
I want to extend question How to store standard error in a variable and get general solution (bash function or functions) to extract from the called function/command together with standard error also all other possible outcomes.
The function should capture and return as vars for the called function/command the following:

stderr
stdout
result string out var
return code

API for the function should be convenient to use.

Example of test function that produces all different output results:
func_to_test_all_outs() {
    local param="${1:?}"; shift
    local -n out_result=${1:?}; shift

    echo "test error output" >&2
    echo "test normal output"

    out_result=""
    if [[ "$param" = "return_string_result" ]]; then
        out_result="result string"
    fi

    return 3
}

More comprehensive/general example of test function that produces all different output results including spawning background processes to produce stout and stderro, interleaving stdout/stderr output, and including leading/trailing/mid white space plus potential command injection, variable expansion, and globbing chars in output streams and does redirection of FD3 in case the calling script relies on that:
func_to_test_all_outs() {
    local param="${1:?}"; shift
    local -n out_result=${1:?}; shift

    ( sleep 2; printf '\n   first  \n$RANDOM *\nerror output\n' >&2; ) &
    exec 3>&1
    printf ' first  \n$(date)\n*\nnormal output\n\n' >&3

    exec 3>&2
    printf '\nsecond $RANDOM *\nerror output\n\n\n' >&3
    ( sleep 2; printf 'second\ntest\n$(date)\n*\nnormal output\n\n' ) &

    ( printf 'third\n$(date)\n*\nnormal output\n\n' ) &

    out_result=""
    if [[ "$param" = "return_string_result" ]]; then
        printf -v out_result '\n\nresult\t\n\nstring\n\n\n'
    fi

    return 127
}


What's the purpose of out_result?

@DonHolgo To return string result from function. In programming general definition of function is like the following: function is something that can get parameters, performs calculation, and return result. out_result here represents such result. This is not the same as return code which is used in bash as error handling mechanism. In particular cases the purpose of out_result will depend on specific functions with implementing some specific algorithms. In bash it is just one of possible out parameter of function that declares like: declare -n out_result=$1 or local -n out_result=$1.

@AntonSamokat but there is no such standard thing in bash (or any POSIX shell, AFAIK). If a function sets a variable as a way to provide some result, it is entirely dependent on the function and who wrote it which variable it will be (or variables, as the case may be). There is REPLY but that's only for read and not general function (mis)use

@muru I did not ask about POSIX solution. namerefs with declare -n or local -n support were added to Bash 5 in January 2019. Related question: in bash what does the -n parameter in "local -n" mean?

Ok, but still doesn't make any difference: whether a function uses namerefs or some other mechanism to send some value to the caller via variable is entirely dependent on the function and who wrote it. There's no reason to think that it will only be the first argument always, or that it will be always be the first argument even in functions that do so in some conditions (it might change behaviour depending on other arguments, the environment, anything)

@muru Right, called function should be bound to some standard/specification/protocol/interface. For example, it must be agreed that the last function argument will be such out result var. For you own functions you have control for implementing such standard. For functions of others that do not correspond to this rule can be written appropriate adapters (dummy functions what will be calling needed non standard functions with required arguments order and pass results to capture functions).

And where is the standard/specification/protocol/interface/adapter/whatever defined? If you have one in mind, you need to specify that in the question. You can't post a question based on some imagined mechanism without describing what exactly it is.

@muru That is why I added my unit tests to show how to use this mechanism. Ok, agree, this needs to be mentioned explicitly. I will think how to describe it in the question.

cat capture.sh

#!/bin/bash

get_tmp_dir() {
    local tmp_dir="/tmp"  # default dir
    local virtual_tmp_dir="/mnt/tmpfs"
    if [ -d "$virtual_tmp_dir" ]; then
        tmp_dir="$virtual_tmp_dir"  # if tmp partition in RAM exsits it will be used
    fi
    echo $tmp_dir
}

DEBUG_ENABLED=0  # 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled
LOG_TO_FILE=0  # 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled
LOG_FILE="$(get_tmp_dir)/capture.log"

script_name=$0

help="
Usage: 

$script_name ( tests | t (tests-alias) | any-test-name | any-func-name [param...] ) [ Options]

Options:

-h, --help
-lc, --log-to-console   Enabling debug logs to be printed to console
-lf, --log-to-file      Enabling logging to file. Log file: $LOG_FILE

--------------------

Examples:

$script_name -h

Running all tests:
$script_name tests

Instead of tests t alias can be used:
$script_name t

Running some specific test (or any other function inside the script with its params) with printing debug logs to console:
$script_name test_capture_stderr -lc

Enabling logging to file:
$script_name t -lf
"

log_info() {  # log version that always prints to console
    local date
    printf -v date '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T' -1;
    local msg="$date - $*"

    printf '%s\n' "$msg"

    if [ "$LOG_TO_FILE" -eq 1 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$msg" >> "$LOG_FILE"
    fi
}

# prints to console only when debug is enabled
# prints to file when logging to file is enabled
log_debug() { 
    if [[ "$LOG_TO_FILE" -eq 0 ]] && [[ "$DEBUG_ENABLED" -eq 0 ]]; then
       return
    fi

    local params=$1; shift
    local param
    for param in "$@"; do
        params+=" '$param'"
    done

    local date
    printf -v date '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T' -1;
    local msg="$date - $params"

    if [ "$LOG_TO_FILE" -eq 1 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$msg" >> "$LOG_FILE"
    fi
    if [ "$DEBUG_ENABLED" -eq 1 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$msg"
    fi
}

# For capturing only stderr
# Captures stderr from a command to a variable while maintaining stdout
# @Args:
# $1: The variable name to store the stderr output
# $2: Vararg command and arguments
# @Return:
# The Command's Return-Code or 1 if missing argument
# source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936303/1455694
capture_stderr() {
  local -n stderr="${1:?}"; shift
  { stderr="$({ "$@" 1>&3; } 2>&1)"; } 3>&1
}

func_to_test_all_outs() {
    local param="${1:?}"; shift
    local -n out_result=${1:?}; shift
    log_debug "func_to_test_all_outs - param: $param; out_result: $out_result"

    echo "test error output" >&2
    echo "test normal output"

    out_result=""
    if [[ "$param" = "return_string_result" ]]; then
        out_result="result string"
    fi
    log_debug "returning result - out_result: $out_result"

    return 3
}

failed_asserts_amount=0
all_asserts_amount=0

assert_equals() {
    local error_message=$1; shift
    local expected_result=$1; shift
    local actual_result=$1; shift

    if [ "$expected_result" != "$actual_result" ]; then
        log_info "$error_message; Expected: $expected_result; Actual: $actual_result"
        (( failed_asserts_amount++ ))
    fi
    (( all_asserts_amount++ ))
}

print_tests_results () {
    if [ $failed_asserts_amount -eq 0 ]; then
        log_info "All tests passed"
    else
        log_info "Number of failed asserts: $failed_asserts_amount"
    fi
    log_info "Total run asserts amount: $all_asserts_amount"
}

# For non english terminal local run with:
# LANG=C ./capture.sh test_capture_stderr
test_capture_stderr() {
    #test for capturing ls command error output
    local expected_stderr="ls: cannot access '123': No such file or directory"
    local actual_stderr
    local expected_return_code=2
    local actual_return_code

    capture_stderr actual_stderr ls "123"
    actual_return_code=$?

    assert_equals "test_capture_stderr" "$expected_stderr" "$actual_stderr"
    assert_equals "test_capture_stderr" "$expected_return_code" "$actual_return_code"

    #test for function
    local expected_stderr="test error output"
    local actual_stderr
    local expected_return_code=3
    local actual_return_code
    local expected="result string"
    local result
    capture_stderr actual_stderr func_to_test_all_outs "return_string_result" result
    actual_return_code=$?

    assert_equals "test_capture_stderr-10" "$expected_stderr" "$actual_stderr"
    assert_equals "test_capture_stderr-20" "$expected_return_code" "$actual_return_code"
}

# Calls specified as parameter command/function and captures
# stderr, stdout, string result and puts them to separate corresponding out params.
# Return code is returned for called command/function.
# See test_capture_all for usage example.
# $1 - name of the variable where the contents of stderr will be stored
# $2 - same but for stdout. But stdout with "no_stdout_redirect" value will skip using it
# $3 - called function string out parameter. "no_result" value will skip using it
# $4 - command/function to be executed
# $5, $6, ... - parameters for the command/function
capture_all() {
    local -n stderr="${1:?}"; shift
    local -n stdout="${1:?}"; shift
    local -n result="${1:?}"; shift # result is string out param, not return code
    log_debug "capture_all - stderr: $stderr; stdout: $stdout; result: $result"

    local tmp_dir="/tmp"
    local virtual_tmp_dir="/mnt/tmpfs"
    if [ -d "$virtual_tmp_dir" ]; then
        tmp_dir="$virtual_tmp_dir"
    fi
    # local tmp_file_for_stderr=$(mktemp)  # standard tmp file creation in /tmp
    local tmp_file_for_stderr=$(mktemp "${tmp_dir}/tmp_file_for_stderr.XXXXXXXXXX")
    local tmp_file_for_stdout=$(mktemp "${tmp_dir}/tmp_file_for_stdout.XXXXXXXXXX")
    log_debug "tmp_file_for_stderr: $tmp_file_for_stderr"
    log_debug "tmp_file_for_stdout: $tmp_file_for_stdout"
    
    # better to separate var declaration with local mark and $? assignment
    local -i return_code
    if [[ "$result" = "no_result" ]]; then
        if [[ "$stdout" = "no_stdout_redirect" ]]; then
            log_debug "extract only stderr"
            "$@" 2> "$tmp_file_for_stderr"
        else
            log_debug "extract both stderr and stdout"
            "$@" 2> "$tmp_file_for_stderr" > "$tmp_file_for_stdout"
        fi
    else
        if [[ "$stdout" = "no_stdout_redirect" ]]; then
            log_debug "extract result string + stderr"
            "$@" result 2> "$tmp_file_for_stderr"
        else
            log_debug "extract all: result string + stderr and stdout"
            "$@" result 2> "$tmp_file_for_stderr" > "$tmp_file_for_stdout"
        fi

    fi

    # this cammand must be the first command after calling "$@"
    return_code="$?"  # return code for called function/command will be also returned
     
    stderr="$(<"$tmp_file_for_stderr")"  # stderr is alsways returned
    if [[ "$stdout" != "no_stdout_redirect" ]]; then
        stdout="$(<"$tmp_file_for_stdout")"
    fi

    log_debug "DEBUG_ENABLED: $DEBUG_ENABLED; LOG_TO_FILE: $LOG_TO_FILE "
    # keep tmp files in case of enabled debug options
    if (( DEBUG_ENABLED != 1 )) && (( LOG_TO_FILE != 1 )); then
        rm -- "$tmp_file_for_stderr" "$tmp_file_for_stdout"
    fi
    return "$return_code"
}

# for capturing only stderr and var with output string result
capture_stderr_outres() {
    local -n stderr2="${1:?}"; shift
    local -n result2="${1:?}"; shift
    log_debug "capture_stderr_outres - stderr: $stderr2; result: $result2"
    local stdout2="no_stdout_redirect"

    capture_all stderr2 stdout2 result2 "$@"
}

test_capture_stderr_outres() {
    local expected_stderr="test error output"
    local actual_stderr
    local expected_return_code=3
    local actual_return_code
    local expected="result string"
    local actual="some previous value"  # to ensure that test will change it

    capture_stderr_outres actual_stderr actual func_to_test_all_outs "return_string_result"
    actual_return_code=$?

    assert_equals "test_capture_stderr_outres-10" "$expected_return_code" "$actual_return_code"
    assert_equals "test_capture_stderr_outres-20" "$expected_stderr" "$actual_stderr"
    assert_equals "test_capture_stderr_outres-40" "$expected" "$actual"
}

test_capture_all() {
    #test for capturing ls error output
    local expected_stderr="ls: cannot access '123': No such file or directory"
    local actual_stderr
    local expected_stdout=""
    local actual_stdout
    local expected_return_code=2
    local actual_return_code

    local actual="no_result"  # disabling string result out var, since ls command does not have out param
    capture_all actual_stderr actual_stdout actual ls "123"
    actual_return_code=$?

    assert_equals "test_capture_all-70" "$expected_stderr" "$actual_stderr"
    assert_equals "test_capture_all-80" "$expected_stdout" "$actual_stdout"
    assert_equals "test_capture_all-90" "$expected_return_code" "$actual_return_code"

    #test for returning string
    local expected_stderr="test error output"
    local actual_stderr
    local expected_stdout="test normal output"
    local actual_stdout
    local expected_return_code=3
    local actual_return_code
    local expected="result string"
    local actual="some previous value"  # to ensure that test will change it

    capture_all actual_stderr actual_stdout actual func_to_test_all_outs "return_string_result"
    actual_return_code=$?

    assert_equals "test_capture_all-10" "$expected_return_code" "$actual_return_code"
    assert_equals "test_capture_all-20" "$expected_stderr" "$actual_stderr"
    assert_equals "test_capture_all-30" "$expected_stdout" "$actual_stdout"
    assert_equals "test_capture_all-40" "$expected" "$actual"

    #test for returning empty result
    local expected=""
    local actual="some previous value"  # to ensure that test will change it
    capture_all actual_stderr actual_stdout actual func_to_test_all_outs "do_not_return_string_result"
    assert_equals "test_capture_all-50" "$expected" "$actual"
}

tests() {
    test_capture_stderr
    test_capture_stderr_outres
    test_capture_all

    print_tests_results
}

t() {
    tests
}

for param in "$@"; do
    case $param in
        -h|--help) echo "$help"; exit ;;
        -lc|--log-to-console) DEBUG_ENABLED=1; log_info "log_debug to console option applied" ;;
        -lf|--log-to-file) LOG_TO_FILE=1; log_info "log to file option applied" ;;
        -*|--*) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1. Use -h flag for help"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

"$@"


capture_stderr — captures only stderr. Example of usage in test_capture_stderr
capture_stderr_outres — captures stderr and called function out var string. Example of usage in test_capture_stderr_outres
capture_all — captures stderr, stdout, called function out var string. Example of usage in test_capture_all

All capture functions also return return code of called function/command.
Help for the script available with -h flag:
./capture.sh -h

Usage: 

./capture.sh ( tests | t (tests-alias) | any-test-name | any-func-name [param...] ) [ Options]

Options:

-h, --help
-lc, --log-to-console   Enabling debug logs to be printed to console
-lf, --log-to-file      Enabling logging to file. Default log file: /tmp/capture.log

--------------------

Examples:

./capture.sh -h

Running all tests:
./capture.sh tests

Instead of tests t alias can be used:
./capture.sh t

Running some specific test (or any other function inside the script with its params) with printing debug logs to console:
./capture.sh test_capture_stderr -lc

Enabling logging to file:
./capture.sh t -lf

Virtual partition in RAM can be created with this recipe: How to make a temporary partition in RAM?
If temporary partition in RAM "/mnt/tmpfs" exists tmp files will be created there, otherwise in standard "/tmp" dir.
Read gurus comments about this approach here. Probably you will not like the idea with using this temporary virtual partition in RAM. It is OK. Just continue using standard "/tmp" dir. And I will continue using the virtual partition until get obvious proofs that "/tmp" dir lives in RAM and not on SSD/HDD degrading them.

Your answer seems to contain vastly more code than required to answer the question that was asked, thereby making it very difficult to find the answer to the question in your code.

@EdMorton without this extra code unit tests for it will not work and it probably will not be convenient for researches to use it. After the code there is description with names of the functions that answer the question. Just use search to find them and check them first. It is not hard to remove such extra code. But it will not be convenient to use the code that cannot be self tested with proper unit tests coverage.

I don't understand that - aren't you just asking in your question how to call a function and get it's stdout, stderr, exit status, and some specific string stored in variables?

@EdMorton Yes, exactly this

However, the unit tests are not essential to the solution, are they? Just move the tests into a separate block (or a paste bin somewhere, maybe) and keep the actual code that answers the post in the main code block

If some part of this code answers the question, please make that obvious. This is relatively dense and complex code, it isn't easy to just glance at it and find the answer to the question. If you feel it is useful, you can include the entire script as an extra, but as it stands this is very confusing.

Ok, I agree. I will make such refactoring.

I added a more comprehensive example function to your question but I can't test it using your script as your script replies on the example function only producing the specific output that's hard-coded in your calling script. A much more concise script that simply prints the stdout, stderr, etc. it collects from the function would be much more useful as an answer to the question you asked.
